# Java Multi-threading prevent two functions running at same time

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating a multi-threaded server and I created a class to manage users, but I noticed that my UserManager class could probably cause errors when one thread is reading the file and other is writing to the file, how to prevent it?

```
package server.questiongiver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import server.engine.CustomLog;

public class UserManager {

    public static User loadUser(String id, Socket s) {
        User user = null;
        if (id == null) {
            return user;
        }
        File f = new File("users.dat");
        if (f.isFile() && f.canRead()) {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.equals("[" + id + "]")) {
                        user = new User(s);
                        user.id = id;
                        user.password = br.readLine().split("-separator-")[1];
                        user.username = br.readLine().split("-separator-")[1];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                CustomLog.error(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return user;
    }

    public static ArrayList<User> loadAllUsers() {
        File f = new File("users.dat");
        ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList();
        if (f.isFile() && f.canRead()) {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.matches("^(\\[[0-9]*\\])$")) {
                        User user = new User(null);
                        user.id = line.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                        user.password = br.readLine().split("-separator-")[1];
                        user.username = br.readLine().split("-separator-")[1];
                        users.add(user);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                CustomLog.error(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return users;
    }

    public static void saveUser(User user) {
        File f = new File("users.dat");
        String content = "";
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        boolean found = false;
        if (f.isFile() && f.canRead()) {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.equals("[" + user.id + "]") && br.readLine().equals(user.password)) {
                        found = true;
                        content += "[" + user.id + "]" + newLine;
                        content += "password-separator-" + user.password + newLine;
                        content += "username-separator-" + user.username + newLine;
                        br.readLine();
                    }
                    else {
                        content += line + newLine;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                CustomLog.error(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            content += "[" + user.id + "]" + newLine;
            content += "password-separator-" + user.password + newLine;
            content += "username-separator-" + user.username + newLine;
        }
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f))) {
            writer.write(content);
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            CustomLog.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            CustomLog.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use `File` if you use Java 7+? Use java.nio.file instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just declare all your Methods in `UserManager` as `synchronized`. This would prevent the methods from beeing executed by multiple threads at the same time.

A better solution, however, would be to use a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) where the `load` oparations use the `ReadLock` and the `save` operation uses the `WriteLock`. The read lock can be acquired by multiple threads at the same time whereas the write lock grants exclusive access to one single thread.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess that declaring all methods synchronized will only prevent it from multiple threads reading or writing at same time and not from one thread trying to write and other trying to read at same time?

Comment: @Ladas125 Synchronizing the methods will prevent other threads from entering them as long as one thread is executing one of them. So synchronizing the methods in your example class will work. If you want to allow multiple reader threads (i.e. threads calling the `load*` methods) but block out any threads during the `save` operation, you should consider a `ReadWriteLock`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look up the `synchronized` keyword.

If you declare all the methods that must be executed exclusively as:

```
public static synchronized User loadUser(String id, Socket s) {
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

They can only be executed with mutual exclusion between threads on that class.
Generally people prefer to make `synchronized` methods non-static but this approach is fine if you're certain that an application will never have two user managers. That sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess that declaring all methods synchronized will only prevent it from multiple threads reading or writing at same time and not from one thread trying to write and other trying to read at same time?

Comment: @ladas125 All the static methods on the class are mutually exclusive. A thread could not be writing while another reading. As Stefan Ferstl if you want many readers but exclusive write you can use a ReadWriteLock however I suspect that is over engineering in a small application. It certainly only helps if there will be frequent concurrent reads.